# Apex trigger: How can I make map values unique if I do not have a common key?

Tags: soql

I am having an issue pulling in a part number in my trigger handler.  I have one object that I was using to key this from, but I just realized this object (ActivityProduct) is not unique in the map.  I think I have been looking at this too long and I am trying to determine how to put a unique value into the map that I can call from the work order object trigger handler.

So here is the set up:

I have a Work Order object that, based on the activity and the product on a work order, we assign an ActivityProduct.  We want to pull a part number from a labor pricing entry object that is tied to the contract via this ActivityProduct.  The problem is when I do a bulk load or update, the handler is pulling the first value in the map into all work orders that have that same Activity Product.  I am not sure what else I could use that would make these unique, unless I somehow append the work order ID into the map as well.  Just not sure the cleanest path forward.  Any ideas?
I have tried to include the important code below.

```
public static void UpdateLaborPN(List<SVMXC__Service_Order__c> triggerNew) 
{
    System.debug('BUNN @@ - BEGIN 4 (UpdateLaborPN). Number of Queries used in this Apex code so far: ' + Limits.getQueries());              

    // Construct the lists
    List<Id> ContractsToQuery = new List<Id>();
    List<Id> PricebooksToQuery = new List<Id>();
    List<Id> DefaultPricebooksToQuery = new List<Id>();          
    List<Id> ActivityProductToQuery = new List<Id>();

    list<SVMXC__Service_Pricebook__c> DefaultPricebook = new list<SVMXC__Service_Pricebook__c>();
    DefaultPricebook = [Select Id from SVMXC__Service_Pricebook__c where Name ='WARRANTY Pricebook'];
    system.debug('TES QUERY CHECK---------> DefaultPricebook ' + DefaultPricebook);

    for (SVMXC__Service_Pricebook__c dpb:DefaultPricebook)
    { 
        if(DefaultPricebook.size() > 0)
            DefaultPricebooksToQuery.add(dpb.Id);
    }

    // Gather the ID(s) from the work order and add to the appropriate list(s).
    for (SVMXC__Service_Order__c wo : triggerNew) 
    {

        // only perform this activity if the work order has NOT been forwarded to SAP...        
        if (wo.NTT_Claim_Status__c != 'Approved' && wo.NTT_Claim_Status__c != 'Forwarded' && wo.NTT_Claim_Status__c != 'Paid')
        { 
            if (wo.BSP_Activity_Product__c != null) 
            {
                ActivityProductToQuery.add(wo.BSP_Activity_Product__c);          
            }
            if (wo.SVMXC__Service_Contract__c != null) 
            {
                ContractsToQuery.add(wo.SVMXC__Service_Contract__c);
                PricebooksToQuery.add(wo.SVMXC__Service_Contract__r.SVMXC__Service_Pricebook__c);
                PricebooksToQuery.add(wo.BSP_Contract_Pricebook__c);
            }
        }
        else
            continue; // Claim is locked, make no changes; exiting...                
    }

    // Query for the contracts and store in a map.
    Map<Id, SVMXC__Service_Contract__c> ContractsMap = new Map<Id, SVMXC__Service_Contract__c>([SELECT Id
                                                                                                , SVMXC__Service_Pricebook__c 
                                                                                                FROM SVMXC__Service_Contract__c
                                                                                                WHERE Id IN :ContractsToQuery]);
                                                                                                system.debug('TES QUERY CHECK---------> ContractsMap - ' + ContractsMap);                                    

    // create a map for labor pricing per Activity Product value
    Map<String, SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c> LaborPricingMap = new Map<String, SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c>();
    // query for the data and build the map using Activity Product as the key        
    for (SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c lp : [SELECT Id
                                       , SVMXC__Activity_Product__c
                                       , SVMXC__Unit__c
                                       , SVMXC__Service_Contract__c
                                       , NTT_Avg_Service_Cost_labor__c
                                       , SVMXC__Regular_Rate__c
                                       , Labor_num__c
                                       , Material_num__c
                                       , Travel_num__c
                                       , Expense_num__c
                                       , AdminFee_num__c
                                       FROM SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c
                                       WHERE SVMXC__Service_Contract__c IN :ContractsToQuery 
                                       AND SVMXC__Activity_Product__c IN :ActivityProductToQuery]) 
                                       {
                                           // add the entry to the LaborPricingMap and use the Activity Product field as the key
                                           LaborPricingMap.put(lp.SVMXC__Activity_Product__c, lp);
                                           system.debug('TES QUERY CHECK---------> lp - ' + lp);                                           
                                       }


    for (SVMXC__Service_Order__c wo : triggerNew) 
    {
        // only perform this activity if the work order has NOT been forwarded to SAP...        
        if (wo.NTT_Claim_Status__c != 'Approved' && wo.NTT_Claim_Status__c != 'Forwarded' && wo.NTT_Claim_Status__c != 'Paid')
        {

            // get the data for this work order
            SVMXC__Service_Contract__c scontract = ContractsMap.get(wo.SVMXC__Service_Contract__c);
            SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c labor = LaborPricingMap.get(wo.BSP_Activity_Product__c);                                                                

            // check to see if we have a contract from the map
            if (labor != null) 
            {     
                // set the value of the Labor PN from the Labor Overrrides
                wo.Labor_Num__c = labor.Labor_num__c;
                wo.Material_Num__c = labor.Material_num__c;
                wo.Travel_Num__c = labor.Travel_num__c;
                wo.Expense_Num__c = labor.Expense_num__c;
                wo.AdminFee_Num__c = labor.AdminFee_num__c;
                wo.BSP_Regular_Rate__c = labor.SVMXC__Regular_Rate__c;
                wo.NTT_Avg_Service_Cost_WO__c = labor.NTT_Avg_Service_Cost_labor__c ;                      
                wo.BSP_Labor_Rate_from_Contract__c = labor.SVMXC__Regular_Rate__c;
                wo.Get_Billing_Part_Nums__c = False;
                continue; // skip any further processing of this work order
            }
        }
        else
            continue; // Claim is locked, make no changes; exiting...      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humble apologies if I've misread this, I don't have a heap of time but wanted to help you get a quick answer. From scanning your code I think you need products for specific contracts, so by combining the contract ID and the Product ID you can get a unique key (assuming products aren't duplicated in contracts):

```
LaborPricingMap.put(lp.SVMXC__Service_Contract__c + '' + lp.SVMXC__Activity_Product__c, lp);
```

Then later on use the same combination of fields from the Service Order:

```
SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c labor = LaborPricingMap.get(wo.SVMXC__Service_Contract__c + wo.BSP_Activity_Product__c);
```

Combining fields to get unique keys like this is not uncommon at all and a standard way of handling such mappings.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought I tried that but ran into an error a while back  Let me give that a shot and I will let you know how it goes.  At least I know I was on the right track in my thinking.  :-) Thanks for your speedy reply!  --Troy

Comment: If you happened to be using an `Id` as the key type for the map then this Would have failed, it needs to be a `String` to append the two values.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  The only issue I see now is that when I discovered this problem today (I originally wrote this about nine months ago), the work orders I was importing all were being updated with the same contract.  But I think I see how I can at least append the strings when pushing them into the map, so I will give it a shot.  I really thought I had tried that before, but again....it WAS 9 months ago and I have slept since then.  I may have tried IDs rather than strings, as you indicated.

Comment: In my experience code I wrote 6 months ago might as well have been written by someone else, 9 months ago is definitely in digging deep :)

Comment: I thought this might work, except I get this error:  Error Error: Compile Error: Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments at line 352 column 6

Comment: Which is this line:  LaborPricingMap.put(lp.SVMXC__Service_Contract__c + lp.SVMXC__Activity_Product__c, lp);

Comment: I guess you need to cast to a string. The quick and dirty way to do this is to just add `+ '' +`: `LaborPricingMap.put(lp.SVMXC__Service_Contract__c + '' + lp.SVMXC__Activity_Product__c, lp);`

Comment: Yeah I have been trying that....still gives me the arithmetic error.  I think I am going in the right direction, so I will keep playing with it.  I will let you know what I find out.  Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43104/discussion-between-laceysnr-and-troy-smith).

Comment: I believe I got it!  Thanks for your help.  Good to know I was on the right track.  It has been a long day, I guess.  I just declared the string first and then referenced it and it works.  Thanks again!

Comment: @TroySmith you could have also used instances of your custom object as a composite key. You can search for examples of that on SFSE.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox!  I will give that a shot too.  I just tested the code using the string and it worked perfectly.  Thanks again, LaceySnr!